# MVC pattern for multi window and multi model desktop application

Tags: c#, windows, model-view-controller, desktop

I am developing a multi window and multi model desktop application for windows platform, based on MVC pattern. Each window is different and is for different purpose, and models are also different except for few common functionalities. I am looking for a sample application or information for my requirement.

Assume if my application has 5 windows each for different purpose and 2 models. Out of 5, if 2 windows for each models and one window for showing something from both models, e.g configurations. Based on these My questions here are,

1. does each window need to have a corresponding controller?
2. Is change in model to be notified to all windows? then interest window would request for data?
3. How to handle user action on common window and any window?

Hope I am not asking too much. I am trying to get bird view of MVC pattern for my requirement so that i can design it properly.

Any help will be appreciated.